# pl/sql фильтрация like

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, выборка

Есть две таблицы: table1 и table2.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Table1 содержит в себе номер аккаунта и "в грязную" написанные имя пользователя, город и сокращенное название города.

Table2 содержит в себе название города и сокращенное название города

Задание: написать запрос, который бы разделил столбец NameCity из table1 на две колонки на основе table2 - если в строке имеется один из городов - вывести только город в отдельную колонку и соответствующее сокращение (или наоборот, если в строке присутствует сокращение - вывести сокращение и соответсвующий город). Ожидаемый результат на скриншоте:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надеюсь, кто-то подскажет решение, все никак не получается реализовать.

UPD: важно разделять именно на основе table2, поскольку строк может быть тысячи
UPD2: таблицы table1 и table2 - https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql80/23cd98a68d501f51d7ab91d710d77c9c/

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119/#12120)

Comment: Добавил ссылку на таблицы

Comment: Если строка содержит одновременно и City, и ShortName, причём из разных записей - что приоритетно?

Comment: Сценарий должен быть следующим: Нужно разделить строку NameCity на 2 строки, но просто обрезать не получится, поскольку в строках может быть лишний мусор (лишняя инфа)
Проверяется каждая строка NameCity из таблицы table1 на совпадения из таблицы table2.
Если совпадения найдены, то данное совпадение выводится в соответствующий столбец, если совпадений нет по строке - выводится NULL.
Например, если найдет только City, а ShortName - нет, выводить значение City, а для ShortName - NULL. Если строка содержит одновременно и City, и ShortName - выводить оба. Ожидаемый результат на 3 скрине.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[онлайн демо для Oracle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/85786/4)

```sql
select t1.accountnumber, t2.* 
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 
    on t1.namecity like '%' || t2.City || '%';
```